# Why does my app's memory footprint explode when I write a multipart

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I have this c# (.NET 4.0) application which uploads local files from the file system using a multi part form request. Here is the request stream:

```
Stream stream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
```

and here is how I upload the file using the stream:

```
byte[] headerbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);
stream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);

using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    { stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead); }
}

byte[] newlineBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n");
stream.Write(newlineBytes, 0, newlineBytes.Length);
```

(the 'stream' is closed later on in the code')

My app runs and it hovers right around 20MB of RAM on the process. When I upload a 100MB file my app jumps to 120MB of RAM. When I upload a 700MB file my app jumps to 720MB of RAM. It does not seem to get garbage collected either. I profiled the app and stream.Write() is what is causing the excess memory allocation.

Is this a leak? What can I do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us how you are identifying used RAM.  High levels of usage of *unused* RAM isn't necessarily a problem, provided the RAM is released when it is needed elsewhere.

Comment: Always funny to see "My app uses memory/CPU/disk... how to stop it?" For memory - don't look at task manager, but instead on .Net perf counters, use memory profiler to verify memory usage (or at least GC.Collect() + [GC.GetTotlaMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations guys. I am reading 'Memory - Private Working Set' which is defined as "Subset of working set that specifically describes the amount of memory a process is using that can't be shared by other processes."

Comment: Maybe the issue not in the writing to another stream, but in request itself? It also might use RAM for file caching. You can try to comment `fileStream.Read\stream.Write` blocks and check again memory usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream returned by the method `GetRequestStream` seems to be write-buffered by default. Together with relatively faster reading from the disk and slower writing to the network interface gives the effect of storing almost complete file in the memory.

You can either try to force the request stream to write the data to the underlying network stream by calling the method `Flush` or try to set the property `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` of the `WebRequest` to `false`.